# What is オー・マイ・ガブリーヌ?

Tags: meaning, katakana, video-games

It's from a video game called Xenogears.  You can play rock-paper-scissors with a man and when he loses he says this:

> 負けたのか、この俺が！？
>   そんなバカな……！？
>   オー・マイ・ガブリーヌ！

Is it something like "Oh my God!"?

Comment: I have a feeling it's a reference to something in the game or someone's name he admires/etc. But yes, it's basically "Oh My God" with a little inside joke.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but there's no a character named "Gabrine"/"Gabriene" in this game.

Comment: ガブリーヌ may refer to "gubline"... what video game you've played? I heard this word used somewhere named "武装神姫", possible in the similar way like OMG does.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto: It's "Xenogears". It can't be reference to "Busou Shinki" because manga was published in 2008 and anime  appeared later, while  "Xenogears" came out in 1998.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

オー・マイ・ガブリーヌ is obviously a pun on オーマイガー ("OMG") and ガブリーヌ, where ガブリーヌ is probably a western surname *Gabreanu*. But according to this, no one seems to know who ガブリーヌ is: [OH MY GABRINO! WHAT DOES THIS XENOGEARS LINE SAY IN JAPANESE?](http://legendsoflocalization.com/oh-my-gabrino-what-does-this-xenogears-line-say-in-japanese/)

[This character speaks in an idiosyncratic manner](http://xenodd.xxxxxxxx.jp/memory/npc01.html) in the first place, so probably there is no special meaning.